# Display message when the JVM is unable to allocate memory from the Operating System

Tags: java, javafx, jpackage

I'm working on a windows desktop application in Java with jpackage. If the operating system does not have enough available free memory to allocate (set by -Xmx param), the JVM crashes without any indication to the user (no console window). I'd like to display a helpful message to the user to create a better experience.

The temp file dump is created with the error (partial dump below). I've tried setting the -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError option to message the user but it does not appear to fire off:

```
java-options=-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=msg %username% OOM
```

I've tried it with a hard coded username as well as the variable without luck. I suspect this isn't the intended use case (more for application heap requests). Is there a way to modify this behavior? Maybe I'm looking at this wrong?

```
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map xxx bytes for G1 virtual space
# Possible reasons:
#   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
#   The process is running with CompressedOops enabled, and the Java Heap may be blocking the growth of the native heap
# Possible solutions:
#   Reduce memory load on the system
#   Increase physical memory or swap space
#   Check if swap backing store is full
#   Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
#   Decrease number of Java threads
#   Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
#   Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
#   JVM is running with Zero Based Compressed Oops mode in which the Java heap is
#     placed in the first 32GB address space. The Java Heap base address is the
#     maximum limit for the native heap growth. Please use -XX:HeapBaseMinAddress
#     to set the Java Heap base and to place the Java Heap above 32GB virtual address.
# This output file may be truncated or incomplete.
#
#  Out of Memory Error (os_windows.cpp:3469), pid=5220, tid=2156
#
# JRE version:  (17.0.1+12) (build )
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (17.0.1+12, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
# No core dump will be written. Failed to create minidump file (0x5).
#

---------------  S U M M A R Y ------------

Command Line: -Djpackage.app-version=0.7.2S -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xmx8g -Xms1g -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=msg %username% OOM -Djpackage.app-path=C:\Program Files\xxx\xxx.exe org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher

Host: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU @ 2.20GHz, 4 cores, 15G,  Windows Server 2019 , 64 bit Build 17763 (10.0.17763.3887)
Time: Wed Mar 22 12:14:51 2023 Central Daylight Time elapsed time: 0.030567 seconds (0d 0h 0m 0s)
```

Comment: Could you not wrap the application execution inside a script that checks for available memory first?

Comment: I can definitely check on startup and give them a warning from code within the JVM. It's not sufficient to catch cases where the memory isn't available later on when the heap size tries to expand though.